# I want to make a post request using postman but I can't find the right object format to send

Tags: spring-boot, httprequest, http-status-code-500

**When I send this object as a post request "http://localhost:8082/student/add", I got a 500 status response from postman.**

**PS : The server is always running and when I send a get request "http://localhost:8082/student/find" it works.**

This is the object i wanna send:

```
{
  "first_name": "Rami",
  "last_name": "BO",
  "modules": [
    {
      "name": "Module 1",
      "subjects": [
        {
          "name": "Subject 1",
          "coefficient": 2,
          "grade": 14
        },
        {
          "name": "Subject 2",
          "coefficient": 3,
          "grade": 16
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Module 2",
      "subjects": [
        {
          "name": "Subject 3",
          "coefficient": 1,
          "grade": 12
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**instead this object was added:**

```
{
        "id": 11,
        "first_name": "Rami",
        "last_name": "BO",
        "modules": [],
        "moyenneGenerale": 0.0
    }
```

**This is my code :**

```js
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Module> modules = new ArrayList<>();
    private double moyenneGenerale;
    
    public Student(String first_name, String last_name, List<Module> modules) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.modules = modules;
    }
}
```

```js
public class Module implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "module")
    private List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "modules")
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Module(String name, List<Subject> subjects) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }
}
```

```js
@Entity
public class Subject {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int coefficient;
    private double grade;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "module_id")
    private Module module;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subjects")
    private List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Subject(String name, int coefficient, double grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.coefficient = coefficient;
        this.grade = grade;
    }
  }
```

**This is the console output:**

> Hibernate: insert into student (first_name, last_name,
> moyenne_generale) values (?, ?, ?) Hibernate: insert into
> student_modules (students_id, modules_id) values (?, ?)

> 2023-05-21T12:53:05.209+01:00  INFO 14596 --- [nio-8082-exec-6]
> o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of
> batch it still contained JDBC statements 2023-05-21T12:53:05.210+01:00
> ERROR 14596 --- [nio-8082-exec-6]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Request processing failed:
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
> transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
> com.example.grademanagement.models.Module] with root cause

Comment: try to add CascadeType.ALL in the relationships. it will create the children objects before creating the parent one.

Comment: Yeah, I've solved the problem by adding "cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST" to the relationships. thanks for the comment it's really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by adding `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` to the relationships to create the children objects before creating the parent one.